# Writer inside a class does not work in a driver

Tags: java, console, reader, writer

I have a Java console application which has different views for different users. Inside of each view I have writer and reader, which are used to displaying and getting data. But when I start my driver code it simply doesn't display required data.

```
public UserView(){
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
}
```

Here is how I initiate my reader and writer inside parent class.

```
public void main(){
    while(true){
        try{
            writer.write("0. Exit\n");
            writer.write("1. View news\n");
            writer.write("2. View personal info\n");
            writer.write("3. Change password\n");
            writer.write("4. Create user\n");
            String ans = reader.readLine();
            switch(ans){
                case "0":
                    return;
                case "1":
                    viewNews();
                case "2":
                    viewPersonalInfo();
                case "3":
                    changePassword();
                case "4":
                    createUser();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main method in admin view

```
public class Main {

    public static UserView view = new AdminView(((Admin)Data.getInstance().getUser("China", "Kaguya")));


    public static void main(String args[]){
        view.main();
    }
}
```

And here is my driver code. How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should have `break`s between all those `case`s.

Comment: You are instantiating `AdminView`, not `UserView`. This subclass may modify the behavior of the superclass, hence, it’s impossible to predict the behavior of this program by only looking at the superclass. On the other hand, if the `AdminView` does not alter the behavior of its superclass `UserView`, it shouldn’t exist.